# Picker Title show top position while click cancel in popup using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, picker, cancel-button

We are using visual material picker control in our app. If I select anything from the picker popup title shows the top and selected value below. If I click cancel from the picker popup title also shows top. It should be in the default state. How to resolve this xamarin forms android and ios?

Screenshoot below:
[image: While click cancel button in picker popup]

[image: Placeholder text moves top. It should be in the default state]

Xaml Code:

```
<local:CustomPicker ItemsSource="{Binding CommentList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComment, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Black" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedIndex="{Binding CommentIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Image="downarrow" Title="Picker" BackgroundColor="White" TitleColor="Gray">
                    </local:CustomPicker>
```

Renderer Code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Material.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer: MaterialPickerRenderer
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd better to post some code and screenshot to describe your problem.

Comment: screenshot added. If we click the cancel button in the picker popup(image1) placeholder text moves top(image2). It should be in the default state. How to resolve this xamarin forms android and ios?

Comment: Maybe you can post some code about Picker, it will help us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have added the code about picker

Comment: You mean that you select one data from picker, then data displaying in Picker correctly, but you click picker downarror icon to open data list, don't choose anything, click cancel, the data still display in picker? I use your code, and can not reproduce your problem, `<local:CustomPicker    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay}"  ItemsSource="{Binding comments, Mode=TwoWay}"   SelectedItem="{Binding selectedcomment, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black" />`

Comment: if I click the cancel, the title of the picker goes top position. It should in the center position

Comment: If I click Picker downarror icon to open data list, scroll to the center of list, click cancel, popup will disappear. If you still have this problem, please post one simple sample at gtihub, I will download your sample to test.